# FREELING error opening file tokenizer.dat

Tags: python, symbols, freeling

I am practicing with freeling using symbol system. When I want to analyze some text I use this code:

```
analyzer -f es.cfg <input.txt> output.txt
```

But this makes this error:

> ```
> TOKENIZER: Error opening file /es/tokenizer.dat
> ```

I have looked for solutions and I tried to put `Analyze` instead of `Analyzer` but it appears another error saying that there is not any internal or external command of analyze. I have also changed the tokenizer dat for the same file of some friends that also use freeling, but it doesn't work.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As described in FreeLing documentation, you should call the "analyze" (no final "r") script, which will take care of setting the default values for the required environment variables.

You are directly calling the "analyzer" binary, so you should set the environment variables yourself.

For a default use of FreeLing, call the "analyze" script, not the "analyzer" binary